# doNothing on a void method but verify its args

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a scenario in which i need a void method to not execute, or `doNothing()` basically.

But i still want to make sure it got the right arguments.

From what i tried it seems like do the `doNothing()` actually doesnt execute the method.

```
 @Test
void whenNoExceptionMetadataAndExceptionThrown_ThenCrateMetadata() throws Exception {
    
    record = new ConsumerRecord<>(topic,partition,offset,partitionKey, bytes);
    doNothing().when(spyProducer)
            .sendMessage(Mockito.any(byte[].class), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(kafkaByteArrConsumer, "handleConsumerRecord", record, acknowledgment);
    Mockito.verify(spyProducer, Mockito.times(1))
            .sendMessage(
                    prepareByteArrMsg(new ExceptionMetaData(null, 0, 0, 0), record.value()),
                    partitionKey, topic);
}
```

this fails, not because the argument isnt matching but because the method was not even invoked.
i confirmed that by swapping all the args to an any matcher and it still didnt pass.

I know one solution to this problem would be just to swap the verify to an `doAnswer()`
where i throw an exception if the args doesnt match what i need. but i feel like this is not the best practice solution...

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but looks like the problem is with byte array. Could you change Mockito.any(byte[].class) to Mockito.any() and check if it helps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not reproducible because, as per the OP, _was actually i threw the wrong exception in the full code_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its kind of embarrassing but the problem was actually i threw the wrong exception in the full code of the snippet i sent, once i changed it it worked...

Ill leave this question here cause its a nice example of how to use a doNothing and check its args

Comment: mark your response as an answer :)

Comment: This is the Solution from the OP and it can't be marked as the answer for 2 days.